# What about Ruby On Rails(RoR) JSON and MySQL for Backend?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, json, backend

in my search for creating a backend, i found that Ruby On Rails can make my day, and of course learning another language it's very fun!, what is your opinion about Ruby on Rails with JSON for the Backend side? i am creating a game for personal project, and i need to get some data to achieve a good gaming experience! so, what are your opinions about this? pros and cons of course, it does not matter the time i will invest, but i guess it is great for learning and break the learning curve, what do you think? Hope you can share your opinions and personal experiences! Thanks!

Comment: When one of the "close reasons" is "Primarily opinion based", it's probably not a good idea to ask "What are your opinions about this?"

Comment: Hahahaha, what about functionality? any suggestion about my questions? i will appreciate it!

Comment: Your question is an opinion poll, and as such does not belong on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to choose a database backend if you are going to build a Rails application. If the data should be structured in JSON, you may choose Mongodb which is very popular solution for noSQL backend. If the game is designed with traditional structure, MySQL and Postgresql are all very good choices supporting your business. ActiveRecord is core of Rails and has well designed APIs and many many powerful methods and helpers that could make your development easy. So using SQL backend DB is a good option.

Comment: Hi canoe! the principal idea is, that i'm working in a game for iOS and Android, so, y need somewhere to store information, and for the learning path, i don't want to use parse.com and other BaaS services,guess i feel more control about my app, so, could i achieve this with MySQL JSON and Ruby On Rails? it is no in fact a game based on Ruby, it is just the way to send and get information from server, could you give me an advice?!! Thank you!

Comment: Sure you can. Rails has very well support to render data in JSON format with RESTful style, so you can get info from the server and post info to the server also with its REST API.